# Array is visualized differently in matplotlib than QGIS

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, numpy, matplotlib

I am getting different resutls when plotting a `np.array` with `matplotlib` than when doing it in an external software - QGIS. Here is what I have:

```
    print(wiw[0].shape)
(1, 8433, 9254)

    print(wiw[0].min())
nan

    print(wiw[0].max())
nan

    print(wiw[0].dtype)
float64
    print(np.nanmin(wiw[0]))
1.0
    print(np.nanmax(wiw[0]))
1.0
```

This is how it looks like when I plot it with `matplotlib`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,20))
ax.imshow(wiw[0][0,:,:], cmap='Greys_r');
```

[image]

Next, I save it with `rasterio` using the following code:

```
with rasterio.open(output_path + 'WIW_TEST.tif', 'w', **ras_meta) as dst:
    dst.write(wiw[0])
```

Where `ras_meta` is:

```
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float64', 'nodata': 0, 'width': 9254, 'height': 8433, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32633), 'transform': Affine(20.0, 0.0, 300000.0,
       0.0, -20.0, 1600020.0), 'blockxsize': 640, 'blockysize': 640, 'tiled': True}
```

If I open this geotiff in QGIS, its appearence is differnet:

[image]

But surprisingly, if I open the saved `geotiff` again with `rasterio` and plot it with `matplotlib`, the visualization is correct. What is going on? Is it a `dtype` issue, a `nodata` problem?

Comment: QGIS and matplotlib both have to stretch/scale the data for display, they're just doing it slightly differently.  You can tweak the stretch in QGIS layer symbology if you want.

Comment: Could be but in this case my array is formed by `np.nan` and `1`. There are not intermediate values. For reference, this array was created with a `np.where` and a condition. Where it was met, `1`. If not, a `np.nan` was put

Comment: Why are you storing binary data as a float?

Comment: If I am not wrong, in order to have `nan`, `float` is needed as `dtype`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this has to do with the styling when drawing on the QGIS canvas, not with any data differences. Have you tried changing your resampling options in the symbology panel of QGIS? For example, change from nearest neighbor to bilinear and tinker with the oversampling to see if that matches what you expect more closely.

You can also try plotting the histogram of the raster when you have it in QGIS to verify the underlying data is being read correctly. If the problem is purely how the raster looks in the QGIS canvas, and you can verify the underlying data is the same, I would not sweat it too much.